# Kendo UI Splitview refresh pane content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I use the Kendo UI [splitview](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/splitview/index.html).

I created one pane (left) for the navigation and one pane (right) for the content.

I got 4 Navigation links for the left pane like this:

```
<div data-role="pane" id="side-pane" data-layout="side-default"
        data-transition="slide">
        <div data-role="view" data-title="test" id="side-root">
            <ul data-role="listview" style="height: 250px" data-style="inset"
                data-style="inset" data-type="group">

                <li>Categories
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="createChart()" data-icon="arrow-e"><a>1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="createLineChart()" data-icon="test"><a>2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="createMap()" data-icon="world"><a>3</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>







    </div>
```

and for the right pane one div's for the map and two div's for the charts like this:

```
<div data-role="pane" data-layout="main-default" id="main-pane">
        <div id="forms" data-role="view" data-title="Form Elements"
            data-init="initForm" data-use-native-scrolling="true" data-show="detailViewShown">





            <div id="map" ></div>
            <div id="chart"></div>
            <div id="linechart"></div>




        </div>
```

The Problem is: when I click on "1" the chart created perfectly. After that happened i click on "2" and the new chart should be created and the old one should be removed, but the new chart appears under the chart "1". How can I refresh or set the right pane content new after the click on navigation items? The same problem for the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to change **data-init** to **data-show**

```
<div data-init="initForm">
```

to

```
<div data-show="initForm">
```

Here is the explanation:

[difference between data-show and data-init](http://www.telerik.com/forums/difference-between-data-show-and-data-init)